# JSONObject.get(key) returning null when mapping exists

Tags: java, json

Code:

```
import org.json.simple

String path = "SomePathHere";

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) (parser.parse(new FileReader(path)));
System.out.println("JSONObject: " + json.toJSONString());
String partner = (String) json.get("partner");
```

Output:

```
JSONObject: {"partner":"website","campaign":"homepage"}
```

So as you can see "partner" exists and has a value associated with it, yet **json.get("partner");** returns null and I don't understand why.

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Works fine for me and prints "website" (used a `StringReader` and put your JSON in it). Are you sure it returns null?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I had the problem backwards. It turns out my issue was that I was trying to get the value of a key called "name" when it's actually called "Name". Darn case-sensitivity.